# Allow distinction between providers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am building an app with flutter and the provider pattern. I have particular one ViewModel, that gets provided with `Provider.of<AddressBookModel>(context)`.

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<AddressBookViewModel>(
          builder:(_) => AddressBookViewModel(),
          child: Scaffold(
              body: _getBody(context);
    }

    Widget _getBody(BuildContext context) {
        AddressBookViewModel vm = Provider.of<AddressBookViewModel>(context);

        // AddressBookViewModel holds a list of contact objects 
        // (id, name, street, starred etc.)
        List<Contact> contacts = vm.contacts; 
        return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: contacts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(contacts[index].name),
                    trailing: contacts[index].starred
                        ? Icon(Icons.star))
                        : null,
                        /**
                         * Changing one object rebuilds and redraws the whole list
                         */
                        onLongPress: () => vm.toggleStarred(contacts[index]);
          ));
    }
}
```

And the respective ViewModel

```dart
class AddressBookViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
    final List<Contact> contacts;

    AddressBookViewModel({this.contacts = []});


    void toggleStarred(Contact contact) {
        int index = contacts.indexOf(contact);
        // the contact object is immutable
        contacts[index] = contact.copy(starred: !contact.starred);
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, once I am changing one contact object in the list with `toggleStarred()`,
the provider is rebuilding and redrawing the whole list. This is not necessary in my opinion, as only
the one entry needs to be rebuild. Is there any way to have a provider that is only responsible 
for one list item? Or any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with lists, you'll want to have a "provider" for each item of your list and extract the list item into a constant – especially if the data associated to your item is immutable.

Instead of:

```dart
final contactController = Provider.of<ContactController>(context);
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: contactController.contacts.length,
  builder: (_, index) {
    reurn Text(contactController.contacts[index].name);
  }
)
```

Prefer:

```dart
final contactController = Provider.of<ContactController>(context);
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: contactController.contacts.length,
  builder: (_, index) {
    reurn Provider.value(
      value: contactController.contacts[index],
      child: const ContactItem(),
    );
  }
)
```

Where `ContactItem` is a `StatelessWidget` that typically look like so:

```dart
class ContactItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactItem({Key key}): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(Provider.of<Contact>(context).name);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, your answer implies that the `Contact` object is also a `ChangeNotifier`, since I want to be able to star the object. But I see an inconsistency in the design of this: When `ContactController` holds a list of contacts and is a `ChangeNotifier`, I would assume I could solve this with another Controller, which is responsible for one single `Contact` object and has the `toggle()` operation. Though, I don't have any problem with your solution, if there is no other way to solve this.

Comment: That does not imply `Contact` being a `ChangeNotifier` at all, no. I used `Provider`, not `ChangeNotifierProvider` :)

Answer (score 1):

### Note : full code available on the end

[image: gistshowng showing the app working with the logs]

### Step 1 :  extend Contact class with ChangeNotifier class

```dart
class Contact with ChangeNotifier {  }
```

### Step 2 :  remove final form **starred** field

```dart
  bool starred;
```

### Step 3 :  move toggleStarred method form  AddressBookViewModel class to Contact  class

```dart
  void toggleStarred() {
    starred = !starred;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

---

Steps[1,2,3] Code Changes Review :

```dart
class Contact with ChangeNotifier {
  final String name;
  bool starred;
  Contact(this.name, this.starred);

  void toggleStarred() {
    starred = !starred;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

### Step 4 : move ListTile to sprate StatelessWidget called ContactView

```dart
class ContactView extends StatelessWidget {
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile();
  }
}
```

### Step 5 : Change ListView itemBuilder method

```dart
(context, index) {
return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: contacts[index],
  child: ContactView(),
);
```

### Step 6 : on the new StatelessWidget ContactView get Contact using Provider

```
final contact = Provider.of<Contact>(context);
```

### Step 7 :change onLongPress to use the new toggleStarred

```dart
onLongPress: () => contact.toggleStarred(),
```

---

Steps[4,6,7] Code Changes Review :

```dart
class ContactView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final contact = Provider.of<Contact>(context);
    print("building ListTile item with contact " + contact.name);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(contact.name),
      trailing: contact.starred ? Icon(Icons.star) : null,
      onLongPress: () => contact.toggleStarred(),
    );
  }
}
```

Steps[5] Code Changes Review :

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: contacts.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    print("building ListView item with index $index");
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: contacts[index],
      child: ContactView(),
    );
  },
);
```

---

### Full Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider<AddressBookViewModel>(
      builder: (context) => AddressBookViewModel(),
      child: HomeScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AddressBookViewModel>(
      builder: (context) => AddressBookViewModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: _getBody(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getBody(BuildContext context) {
    AddressBookViewModel vm = Provider.of<AddressBookViewModel>(context);

    final contacts = vm.contacts;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: contacts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        print("building ListView item with index $index");
        return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: contacts[index],
          child: ContactView(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// product_item.dart
class ContactView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final contact = Provider.of<Contact>(context);
    print("building ListTile item with contact " + contact.name);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(contact.name),
      trailing: contact.starred ? Icon(Icons.star) : null,
      onLongPress: () => contact.toggleStarred(),
    );
  }
}

class AddressBookViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final contacts = [
    Contact("Contact A", false),
    Contact("Contact B", false),
    Contact("Contact C", false),
    Contact("Contact D", false),
  ];
  void addcontacts(Contact contact) {
    contacts.add(contact);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Contact with ChangeNotifier {
  final String name;
  bool starred;
  Contact(this.name, this.starred);

  void toggleStarred() {
    starred = !starred;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

### Ref :

- [Simple app state management - Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)
- [[Question] Nested Providers and Lists · Issue #151 · rrousselGit/provider](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/151)